# Is there a way to represent the 21 october 2012 in a Javascript `Date` object?

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

I noticed something weird with timezones and Javascript `Date` object.

Trying this on a Linux box:

```
$ TZ='America/Sao_Paulo' js 
js> new Date(2012, 9, 21, 0, 0, 0).toString() 
"Sat Oct 20 2012 23:00:00 GMT-0300 (BRST)"
```

I found it impossible to get an object that represents the 21th of october 2012. Every attemps to get a `Date` between 00:00 and 01:00 that day results in a date the day before between 11:00 PM and 00:00.

(Windows user may change their timezone to Brasilia/GMT-03 to experience the same behavior)

Adding one hour (or one day) to such a date object results in getting back **the same date**.

I guess it has to do with daylight saving time which occurs on that specific date in Brazil, however I absolutely don't know how to deal with that.

I have a loop that iterates over the days of the month (for a calendar application) and it obviously loops forever in that case when reaching the 20th of october 2012.

There must be something I'm doing wrong, but I don't know how to deal with such a case, as I guess it could also happen for other timezones.

What is the recommended way of dealing with `Date` in Javascript to ensure that such timezone/daylight saving time related problems do not occur ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an absolutely correct behavior. Due to the DST midnight simply does not exist in local time in Brazil on October 21st. If you just need to build a calendar you can just use `new Date(2012, 9, 21, 0, 0, 0).toUTCString()` instead of `new Date(2012, 9, 21, 0, 0, 0).toString()` and other [UTC methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

For example to create an UTC date you can use `new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 9, 21, 0, 0, 0));`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However my problem is not getting the string representation of the date, but getting a validd object that represents this exact moment.

Comment: Then just use UTC method: `new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 9, 21, 0, 0, 0));`

Comment: That works better indeed. Could you please edit your answer to make it more obvious what the real solution is ? I will be glad to accept it then :)

Comment: I edited it already, think it answers your question better now.

Comment: I don't believe this is correct. It's a transition *forward* - so there's a gap in local times, *not* an ambiguity. (You get ambiguity when local time moves backward, so the same local time occurs twice.) In fact, midnight simply didn't exist in local time in Brazil on October 21st.

Comment: @Jo In fact the OP asked not about the reason of his problem but for the solution. I edited the answer to make it abolutely correct.

Comment: @bjornd: You're still claiming it's correct behaviour for Javascript to give a result of 11pm. It's not. There are various options which are reasonable, but none of them is to go *back* an hour. Would you think it okay to return 10pm? 11:35pm?